# i get error when i am trying to get update to install docker on Debian

Tags: docker

when i am trying to get update to install docker on Debian 10 i get Errors

```
Ign:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster InRelease
    Fehl:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster Release
      Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 52.85.183.164 443]
    OK:1 http://security-cdn.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
    OK:4 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
    OK:5 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
    Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
    E: Das Depot »https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster Release« enthält keine Release-Datei.
    N: Eine Aktualisierung von solch einem Depot kann nicht auf eine sichere Art durchgeführt werden, daher ist es standardmäßig deaktiviert.
    N: Weitere Details zur Erzeugung von Paketdepots sowie zu deren Benutzerkonfiguration finden Sie in der Handbuchseite apt-secure(8).
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, when I experimented with certificates.

I would recommend to reproduce the steps recommended in [Docker install Debian](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/)

Did you import any certificates on your own?

Comment: Hello there, i recommended all steps in Docker Website. No i didn't import any certificates on my own? Thx

Comment: Just to exclude any certificate problem, try installing ca-certificates by running `sudo apt install ca-certificates`. If it was already installed run `sudo update-ca-certificates -f`. This relinks all needed root-certificates in order to check that the Docker certificate is valid.

Comment: I installed  the ca-certificates but stil get the same errors ):

Answer (score 0):

sudo update-ca-certificates -f  << this worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).